# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape in python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a newbie in using python 2.7.
I run this command

```
python plot_bands_gnu.py
```

but get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_bands_gnu.py", line 16, in <module>
    ebands [:,ib] = databands[idx1:idx2,1]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50) into shape (60)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You have an array with 60 elements and one with 50 elements. You can't apply a binary operator to them.

Comment: Error message explanation: first line is just general syntax, second line tells you the error happens at line 16 of your `plot_bands_gnu.py`, third line tells you the content of that line, and the fourth line is the type and reason of the error: on that line you have made a mistake that assign (`=`) the values of a 50 length array `databands[idx1:idx2,1]` to a 60 length array `ebands [:,ib]`.

Comment: thank you for the response. do u have any idea how to correct the mistake?